# Split multi-page PDF into JPG (or PNG...) files using ImageMagick

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, split

I'm facing a little problem with Image Magick, which I found a marvellous tool so far, but here it doesn't achieve what I expect (N.B: I work in Windows 7)
I read that, to split a 3 pages (for example) pdf file, you just have to do:

```
img2img My3pageFile.pdf SplittedImage.jpg
```

and then, ImageMAgick would automatically create SplittedImage-1.jpg, SplittedImage-2.jpg and SplittedImage-3.jpg.

Well instead of this, I obtain an error message like this: (let me hope you'll believe me if I say that I have no doubt here under that the file "benef.pdf" does exist on D:).

```
D:\>img2img benef.pdf benef.jpg
img2img: `%s': %s "gswin32c.exe" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dPARANOIDSAFE -dBATCH 
-dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dEPSCrop -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=0
"-sDEVICE=pnmraw" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-g595x842" "-r72x72"
"-sOutputFile=C:/Users/ADM-A2~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-o3McMMZQ" "-fC:/Users
/ADM-A2~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-EOLT_ZO2" "-fC:/Users/ADM-A2~1/AppData/Local
/Temp/magick-mUWMMcc0".
img2img: Postscript delegate failed `benef.pdf'.
img2img: missing an image filename `benef.jpg'.
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simply to install and download GhostScript at the following address, after what the instruction I gave at the beginning works perfectly well.
So here's the link:

```
http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/
```